Обязателен ли знак вопроса в таких предложениях?
Где, как не здесь, ведётся разработка всех проектов.
Со знаком вопроса получится риторический вопрос. А можно ли поставить точку?

Правильно:
Где, как не здесь, ведётся разработка всех проектов.
Пояснение

Предложение утвердительное, оборот речи "где, как не здесь" имеет значение "именно здесь". Поэтому вопросительный знак не нужен.

Можно посмотреть похожие примеры в ответах Справочной службы:


Где, как не здесь, искать вдохновение! Где, как не здесь, можно увидеть...  Вид предложения (вопрос, утверждение или восклицание) выбирается по контексту.

Как выбирается? Можно представить такой вариант. В начале текста в принципе можно поставить вопросительный знак, если дальше идет раскрытие темы. А если это вывод в конце  из ранее сказанного, то  тогда у нас утверждение, поэтому ставим точку.

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Тема риторических вопросов в общем плане обсуждалась на форуме, там есть интересные материалы и ссылки на Розенталя и ПАС:
Розенталь: § 72. Вариативные знаки препинания »» Вопросительный знак — восклицательный знак ПАС: § 1. Знаки препинания в конце предложения
Форум: Где бы (ни) работать, как не здесь? Нужен ли вопросительный знак?
